# How to reset row's value in Pandas for a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

For example:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['name'] == 'x':
       row['name'] = 'xxx'
```

Then how to write the updated row back to the df? Something like:

```
  df[index] = row
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['name'] == 'x':
       df.loc[index,'name'] = 'xxx'
```

Comment: I have a few more 'if row[]' checking statements and update the row conditionally. I want to update the row once at the end of all if checking. Is that possible using 'df[index] = row'?

Comment: @marlon possible  `df[index] = row` row should be list of value

Answer (score 0):

If you want update your column based on if, i suggest:
df['column'] = df.column.apply(lambda x: "value if true" if x == 'x' else 'value if false')

column is the name of the column that you want to update

Comment: this simple line seems working: df.at[index] = row